# excel vba how to copy the value of multiple non-contiguous ranges into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the value of multiple non-contiguous ranges into an array. I wrote code like this:

```
summaryTempArray = .range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15").Value
```

But it copies only the first part (A2:D9). Then, I tried the following and I get the error - "Method Union of Object _Global Failed" - is there any mistake in the way that I am using union?

```
summaryTempArray = Union(.range("A2:D9"), .range("A11:D12"), .range("A14:D15")).Value
```

Comment: just use split applied to the range's address , separator being ","

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know what was wrong with your `union`, but it would have created the same range, which you stated in your first attempt.

The problem is, you have now multiple areas. Which you can, and as far as I know, has to address now.

Here is an example, which will resolve in an array of all areas, without adding each cell individually, but adding each area individually to the summary array:

```
Public Sub demo()
  Dim summaryTempArray() As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  With Tabelle1
    ReDim summaryTempArray(1 To .Range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15").Areas.Count)

    For i = 1 To .Range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15").Areas.Count
      summaryTempArray(i) = .Range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15").Areas(i)
    Next i
  End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Jook's solution is as good as you are going to get if it is important to get the source ranges into an array.  However, I think the solution should include instructions on extracting values from a ragged array.  This is not difficult but the syntax is obscure.

I cannot get your `Union` statement to fail either.  I assume  there is something about the context that causes the failure which I cannot duplicate.

The code below shows that the two ranges are the same and that only the first sub-range is loaded to an array as you reported.  It finishes with an alternative approach that might be satisfactory.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Dim CellValue() As Variant
  Dim rng As Range

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set rng = .Range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15")
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    Set rng = Union(.Range("A2:D9"), .Range("A11:D12"), .Range("A14:D15"))
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    ' The above debug statements show the two ranges are the same.

    Debug.Print "Row count " & rng.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print "Col count " & rng.Columns.Count
    ' These debug statements show that only the first sub-range is included the
    ' range counts.

    CellValue = rng.Value

    Debug.Print "Rows " & LBound(CellValue, 1) & " to " & UBound(CellValue, 1)
    Debug.Print "Cols " & LBound(CellValue, 2) & " to " & UBound(CellValue, 2)
    ' As you reported only the first range is copied to the array.

    rng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    ' This shows you can copy the selected sub-ranges.  If you can copy the
    ' required data straight to the desired destination, this might be a
    ' solution.

  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & tried a few methods without success until I hit on this:-

```
    dim i as integer
    Dim rng1 as range
    Dim str as string
    dim cels() as string
    Set rng1 = sheet1.Range("A2:D9,A11:D12,A14:D15")
    str = rng1.address(0,0)
    cels() = split(str, ",")     '<--- seems to work OK
    for i = 0 to 2
        Debug.Print cels(i)
    Next i
```

I would be interested if this is an "incorrect" conversion method.

Comment: It seems to me that this is just a roundabout way to loop on the Areas of `rng1`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a multi dimensional array from non concurrent cell ranges. What I did was use a bit of the code above for the range copy mechanic I learned 2 things; that with that method you can refer to the actual cells and not just the data and you can also move and preserve order with it. In my personal project we have to use some excel files to fill out calibration data. It runs the calculations and produces a report of calibration record for our files to refer to later. These stock files are boring! I wanted to spruce it up a bit and color most of the documents empty cells depending on if the calibration passed or not. The files separate the individual check steps so the ranges I wanted to look through were not always adjacent. What I came up with is to use the copy function below to create a new sheet and paste all the non-concurrent ranges into one nice new set of concurrent ones and then have my array look at the new sheet to draw my table. I have it run the lookup I needed and then get rid of the now useless sheet.

```
Public Sub ColorMeCrazy()


' First Declare your variables that you will need line notes will be added to all the ones for just the array problem
Dim chkarray As Variant

Dim i As Integer ' for the array lookup loop
Dim j As Integer ' also for the array lookup loop

Dim chk1 As Boolean
Dim chk2 As Boolean

Dim cpyrange As Range ' the non-concurrent range collector haha.
Dim cz As Range

chk2 = True

Set cz = Worksheets("AN_PRM-36").Range("A1:I1,C2:I2,I3:I35,A30:H32,D33:H35,C34:C35,A36:E36,A22:H23,D24:H24,A16:H16,A8:H9,D10:H10")

' the next item below sets the ranges i wish to use. see that they arent all just right next to eachother.
Set cpyrange = Worksheets("AN_PRM-36").Range("G7:H7,G15:H15,G21:H21,G28:H29")

' this is the new sheet i made to create the array with
Sheets.Add.Name = "AN_PRM-36tmp"

' the data gets coppied to the new sheet but now its all together
cpyrange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("AN_PRM-36tmp").Range("A1")

' now i tell the array i want it to use the data on the new sheet
chkarray = Worksheets("AN_PRM-36tmp").Range("A1:B5")

'this was my look up for the nonsense that i wanted to do later
For i = LBound(chkarray, 1) To UBound(chkarray, 1)
        
    For j = LBound(chkarray, 2) To UBound(chkarray, 2)
        
        Debug.Print chkarray(i, j)
            If chkarray(i, j) = "Pass" Then
            chk1 = True
            Else
            chk2 = False
            End If
    Next
Next

If chk1 = True And chk2 = True Then
cz.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

Else
cz.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End If

' this last bit will get rid of the new sheet and not ask you are you sure you want it gone.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("AN_PRM-36tmp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```