# Excel: Trying to Loop Through number of cells

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am using excel 2003 with a file consisting of 65000 rows, and I am trying to:

**copy rows 1 to 3**

**skip 496**

**copy rows 497 to 500**

**skip 496**

**copy rows 997 to 1000**

**And So On, keep going until 65000**

Also If anyone has a good Row counter code, that would be great!

The following is my code and I am having a hard time figuring the syntax for the Worksheets copy line. If anyone can help me figure it out that would be great.

Thanks!

```
Sub RowCopy()

Dim i As Integer

Dim o As Integer


i = 1

o = 3

While o < 65000 'RowCount

**Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i :"H" & o).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A"&i:"H"&o)**

i = i + 495

o = o + 496

End



End Sub
```

Comment: You mean? :

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i ":" "H" & o).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A"&i ":" "H"&o)

There is still an error

Comment: Like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246885/excel-vba-how-to-copy-the-value-of-multiple-non-contiguous-ranges-into-an-array)?

Comment: Range("A" & i & ":H" & o)

Comment: skipping those values till 65000

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a string that represents a range, but your string concatenation syntax is wrong.  It should be

```
    Range("A" & i & ":H" & o)
```

Also, Integer data type can only hold values -32768 to 32767.  To cope with 65000, use Long