# Combine a series of discrete ranges to be read into an array at once in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a for loop that produces one range per loop in the following format:

```
MsgBox currentRange.Address
```

Outputs

```
$A$4:A$1000
$D$4:D$1000
$Z$4:Z$1000
```

One value per loop.

How can I combine all these ranges into a larger range to be read into an array using vba code.

I tried using something like

```
bigRange = Application.Union(bigRange, currentRange)
```

Within the loop, however this does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246885/excel-vba-how-to-copy-the-value-of-multiple-non-contiguous-ranges-into-an-array

Comment: what do you mean by does not work ? be specific. the error message often gives the answer itself, here probably being"Object not `Set`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Set bigRange = Application.Union(bigRange, currentRange)
```

You forget `Set`. It needs because Range is object. To get addrese use `bigRange.Address`.

Also be sure to initialize bigRange

```
If bigRange Is Nothing Then
   Set bigRange = currentRange
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I had also not initialized bigRange   If bigRange Is Nothing Then
            Set bigRange= currentRange
        End If`