# Replace the VBA code into Arrays for fast processing

Tags: excel, vba

This code works on a small amount of data, filtered or not.

```vb
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim specialCharacters As String
specialCharacters = " !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"",.<>/?\|"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For Each cell In Selection
    For i = 1 To Len(specialCharacters)
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, Mid(specialCharacters, i, 1), "")
    Next i
Next cell
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

When I convert this code into arrays, when it pastes the data to the cells it was exact copy of the above cells and some of them give an error #NA.

```vb
Sub RemoveSpecialCharacters()
    Dim cellValues  As Variant
    Dim i           As Long, j As Long
    Dim specialCharacters As String
    specialCharacters = "        ':"",.<>/?|"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim filteredRange As Range
    Set filteredRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each Area In filteredRange.Areas
            cellValues = Area.value
            For i = 1 To UBound(cellValues, 1)
                For j = 1 To UBound(cellValues, 2)
                    Dim value As String
                    value = cellValues(i, j)
                    For k = 1 To Len(specialCharacters)
                        value = Replace(value, Mid(specialCharacters, k, 1), "")
                    Next k
                    cellValues(i, j) = value
                Next j
            Next i
            Area.value = cellValues
        Next Area
    End If
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if `filteredRange` is not a continguous block of cells, you can't use `.Value` to read all its data into one array in one step. Nor can you write an array to `.Value`. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246885/excel-vba-how-to-copy-the-value-of-multiple-non-contiguous-ranges-into-an-array) is useful.

Comment: Thank you and i got you and updated the code in the question but getting an error on this line type mismatch `For i = 1 To UBound(cellValues, 1)`

Comment: I suspect that `Area` in this case is a single cell... another edge case. The `.Value` of a single cell is not an array.

Comment: Alright let me explain i just copied that code from google and make little changes according to my need but i am not an expert like you but beginner. I would appreciate if you can help me out by giving solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping cell-by-cell, try using `Range.Replace` here. The following is semi-tested:

```
Sub RemoveSpecialCharacters(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim specialCharacters As String
    specialCharacters = " !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"",.<>/?\|"

    Dim wildcards As String
    wildcards = "?~*"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(specialCharacters)
        Dim specialCharacter As String
        specialCharacter = Mid$(specialCharacters, i, 1)
        
        ' Escape wildcards using the ~
        If InStr(wildcards, specialCharacter) > 0 Then
            specialCharacter = "~" & specialCharacter
        End If
        
        rng.Replace _
            What:=specialCharacter, _
            Replacement:="", _
            LookAt:=xlPart
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like the following:

```
RemoveSpecialCharacters rng:=Selection
```

or

```
RemoveSpecialCharacters rng:=Selection.Cells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Note that `Selection.Cells(xlCellTypeVisible)` may return unexpected results if `Selection` is a single cell.

In that case, use:

```
If Selection.CountLarge > 1 Then
    RemoveSpecialCharacters rng:=Selection.Cells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Else
    RemoveSpecialCharacters rng:=Selection
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but i have found one problem while using it. the code works perfect on more than one selected cell but when it comes to single cell it removes the formulas from aroud cells. I really do not know why. @BigBen

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `Selection.Cells(xlCellTypeVisible)` on a single cell. Calling visible cells on a single cell will have this behavior.

Comment: Yes your right. I am using! any solution to this?

Comment: You need to check `If Selection.CountLarge > 1` before using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Thanks i got you but i want to work it on single cell as well

Comment: Then use `Else` with just `Selection` (edited the answer)

Comment: Thank you so much i almost spent an hour to fix the problem but could not. Thank you once again.